# GWT HashMap.put() not adding data to the HashMap

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, hashmap

I have a game created in LibGDX that uses GWT to build an HTML5 version. I've got a hashmap that I use for logging purchases and some purchases were being processed multiple times. Looking into it I discovered it's because they weren't being added to the hashmap. The logic that adds processes to the hashmap is as follows (and works fine on Desktop, iOS and Android versions):

```
public void updatePurchase(String orderNo, UserPurchase purchase) {
    Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "In updatePurchase " + orderNo);

    if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(orderNo) || purchase == null) return;
    Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "1");

    synchronized (this) {
        Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "2");
        UserPurchase existingPurchase = purchases.get(orderNo);
        Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "3 " + (existingPurchase != null));
        if (existingPurchase == null) {
            Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "4 " + purchases.containsKey(orderNo));
            purchases.put(orderNo, purchase);
            Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "5 " + purchases.containsKey(orderNo));
            setUpdated();
        } else {
            Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "6");
            if (existingPurchase.status == UserPurchase.STATUS_NEEDS_PROCESSING && purchase.status == UserPurchase.STATUS_PROCESSED) {
                Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "7");
                existingPurchase.status = UserPurchase.STATUS_PROCESSED;
                Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "8");
                setUpdated();
            }
        }
    }

    Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "Leave updatePurchase " + orderNo);
}
```

This produces the following output

```
GWT: WBLOG: Double Purchase: In updatePurchase 787349198062445
GWT: WBLOG: Double Purchase: 1
GWT: WBLOG: Double Purchase: 2
GWT: WBLOG: Double Purchase: 3 false
GWT: WBLOG: Double Purchase: 4 false
GWT: WBLOG: Double Purchase: 5 false
GWT: WBLOG: Double Purchase: Leave updatePurchase 787349198062445
```

Specifically note log lines 4 and 5, the hashmap does not contain the key `orderNo`. I then call `put` and on the next line the hashmap still doesn't contain the key `orderNo`.

This one really has me stumped. I use hashmaps all over the game and this is the only one that isn't working as expected. There are no errors reported in the console and nothing else unexpected appears to be happening.

### Edit

I decided to try this:

```
        while (!purchases.containsKey(orderNo)) {
            Gdx.app.log("Double Purchase", "Trying to add purchase " + count++);
            purchases.put(orderNo, purchase);
        }
```

It just gets stuck in an infinite loop. It's a very stubborn `HashMap`!

### Edit

Next interesting point. The `String` that is used for `orderNo` is returned from the Facebook SDK as part of a `JavaScriptObject`. The code for this is below:

```
public class PurchaseResponse extends JavaScriptObject {
    protected PurchaseResponse() {
    }

    public final native String getPaymentId() /*-{
        return this.payment_id;
    }-*/;

    public final native double getAmount() /*-{
        return this.amount;
    }-*/;

    public final native String getCurrency() /*-{
        return this.currency;
    }-*/;

    public final native int getQuantity() /*-{
        return this.quantity;
    }-*/;

    public final native String getRequestId() /*-{
        return this.request_id;
    }-*/;

    public final native String getStatus() /*-{
        return this.status;
    }-*/;

    public final native String getSignedRequest() /*-{
        return this.signed_request;
    }-*/;
}
```

I get an exception when trying to do `indexOf()` on this this string with the message that the `indexOf()` method doesn't exist. `indexOf()` does exist and works perfectly well in GWT on normal Strings. What's special about this String? I've tried doing new `String(orderNo)` and the new String doesn't work as expected either.

Comment: Are you synchronizing on the right bject?  If the `purchases` variable is not an instance field of `this`, then you could have multiple threads locking on different objects; i.e. no mutual exclusion and improper synchronization.

Comment: @StephenC It is an instance field and as this is GWT it's all single threaded anyway, so the synchronized should have no effect.

Comment: Does the `put()` call never add an item to the `HashMap` or just in some cases? If the latter, can you identify any similarities between the cases?

Comment: Are you sure that purchases is a java.util.HashMap? In classic devmode i couldnt reproduce this behaviour. I try it in production mode in a couple of minutes :)

Comment: @Baz It works sometimes - but I'm not sure why or what the pattern is.

Comment: @mam10eks Yes it is, I can't reproduce it in dev mode either, only in production and only in this instance of a HashMap.

Comment: @WillCalderwood My test with a String as key works in dev- and production-mode. Could you please sysout the size of purchases too?

Comment: @WillCalderwood Can't reproduce this either. I'm using `HashMap`s in multiple places and never had a problem with them. You've got a curious case there.

Comment: @Baz I have 78 places where I create HashMaps in my code - this is the only place I have an issue too. Very curious.

Comment: @mam10eks Interesting idea about outputting the size. The size does indeed increase after the `put()`. So it's as if there's something going wrong with the hashing and it can't find it after it's added it.

Comment: @WillCalderwood Does `get()` ever return an object when `containsKey()` returns `false` in your case?

Comment: @Baz No. Looking at the `HashMap` code `containsKey()` calls `getEntry()`. I wish I could step through this code in a meaningful way!

Comment: @WillCalderwood Right, so if the size increases, what does `keySet()` and `values()` return?

Comment: @WillCalderwood Could you iterate over the EntrySet and compare the keys of each Entry with your orderNo? You could also compare the `hashCode()`

Comment: @Baz I'm on the case. I've just added some more interesting info to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @mam10eks I'm on the case. I've just added some more interesting info to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @mam10eks This `String` always returns a hashcode of 0. It would appear the `String` is the problem rather than the `HashMap`.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new String, set the value of the newly created String to the value of the parameter and use the new String variable to put the value in the HashMap?

Comment: @ElHoss I've tried `new String()` which didn't work. I'm just trying all sorts ways of creating new strings to see what works (if anything).

Comment: @WillCalderwood but only an empty string should have a `hashCode()` of 0. Could you print the class of `orderNo` ? I hope its a derivate of a usual String (that overrides `hashCode`) xD

Comment: Or a String that consists only of NUL-characters. But we could see that your String consists of some digits. Hence the hascode must be greater than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out! According the [Facebook example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/reference/paydialog) the JSON response is as follows:

```
{
  payment_id: "495869257196092",
  amount: "5.00",
  currency: "USD",
  quantity: "1", 
  request_id: "60046727",
  status: "completed", 
  signed_request: "7QYHzKqKByA7fjiqJUh2bxFvEdqdvn0n_y1zYiyN6tg.eyJhbGCJxdWFudGl0eSI6IjEiLCJzdGF0dXMiOiJjb21wbGV0ZWQifQ"
}
```

But on inspecting  the actual JSON response it's this:

```
{  
   "payment_id":795448840585614,
   "amount":"0.79",
   "currency":"GBP",
   "quantity":"1",
   "request_id":"xxxx",
   "status":"completed",
   "signed_request":"xxx"
}
```

Note the crucial difference. `payment_id` is a numeric value and not a `String` hence the missing functions and the fact that it wasn't performing as a `String` should.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!